# Laravel 5.5 eloquent creation table

Tags: laravel, eloquent

any of you know how to create tables in laravel through Eloquent without adding the final s to the name of these?

For instance after the creation with this commands:

```
php artisan make:model Article -crmf

php artisan migrate
```

The table in database will be named as Articles. If I try to change the name in the respective file as Article i receive error during the execution of query,like:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:

How can I create table without the adding of final S ?

thanks

Comment: in your model protected $table = 'article'

Comment: Genuine question... would you not want the "articles" table? As in a table that stores info on the articles (plural)? I'm new to all of these naming and case conventions, so just trying to understand why you might not want it as a plural.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs:

> Table Names
>
> By convention, the "snake case", plural name of the class will be used as the table name unless another name is explicitly specified.

So, in this case, Eloquent will assume the Article model stores records in the  articles table. You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'article';
}
```